# self-signed CA next to signed CA?

Tags: tls, openssl

What I'm trying to do is implement client-certificate authentication on my website (running on Apache).

From this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62305/how-do-i-get-a-third-party-signed-ssl-client-certificate/62327#62327?newreg=a46cea0aa5bc4156b048c1018d7363c9) I understand that it's not possible to generate a client certificate myself based on a signed certificate (published by for instance Comodo).

My question is; For any website on for instance Apache, can I use a self-signed CA with which I verify my users (by them importing a client-certificate) and at the same time use a signed certificate so that 'the url bar' goes green?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The certificate used to authenticate the server and the client do not have to be issued by the same entity. It is totally possible for you to set the web-server up with a certificate you bought and in the meantime create your own Public Key-Infrastructure to handle client certificates.

The authentication process is not mutual, so this situation is possible and yet remains secure thanks to asymmetric cryptography and proper trust chain.